# Acer Aspire 4736Z BIOS Bricked (failed flash bios update)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, bios, acer-aspire

So as the title says, I bricked my laptop. I'm not that good at explaining but let me try. I reformatted my laptop and installed the drivers given by the acer support driver and manual site and noticed that my speakers aren't working. I opened my laptop to check if the speakers are still okay or the pins might have been disconnected.

So it was still okay, after a couple of minutes searching, I found out that I needed to update my BIOS and so I did (yes I checked the version first). Everything was going as planned except for some reason there was an error on memory block `0xFFFFF100`. It didn't give me any more details except `Error on Memory Block 0xFFFFF100` and decided to shut it self down. I've started my laptop and it gave me the dead screen.

I've been trying the Flash Drive <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> method, but as to no avail (it's still running and it was for the whole day 3 days ago, switched to another port next day and same thing). It's not doing anything.

Does anyone know how to reflash or restore the stock BIOS?

Comment: So you have a FAT32 formatted 4GB or smaller flash drive with the BIOS file, plugged into the right-hand side USB port, and you hold down Fn+Esc while powering up and nothing happens? No USB drive activity, no flashing power light, nothing on the screen, etc?

Comment: oh ye I forgot to add that.. ye I have it formatted as FAT and yep still doesn't work.. except the power button is on.. but as far as I know it won't take a whole day to do it right?

EDIT: another thing to add, I've tried FD, BIN, and ROM still doesn't work
BIOS file name is currently ZG-something-32.FD

Comment: It takes less than 10 minutes iirc, you should see USB activity for a bit (like 15 seconds or so) when the recovery process starts... I think it reboots on it's own when done. The fact you got an error could indicate a bad BIOS chip, if you are not getting USB activity, or a flashing power light (if so, press the power button ONCE), it could mean the BIOS is toast and the embedded recovery tool is lost as well. :/

Comment: wait.. I just found out something... might help
I'm actually using a 4GB microSD card and uses an USB adapter (not an SD size adapter) and no it doesn't have any "lock"
but my other laptop reads it as write-protected - but if I install it on my phone I can read and write normally... is it because of my adapter?

Comment: possibly... Get a real USB 2.0 flash drive that is 4gb or smaller